# A sum over a hyperplane in $\mathbb{Z}^4$

Tags: inequalities, nonlinear-optimization

Fix $M \geq 2$. What is the smallest number $\tau = \tau(M)$ such that $$\sum_{a,b,c,d =1\\ a + b = c+ d}^M (x_a x_b x_c x_d)^{\tau/4} \leq 1,$$ for all  $x , \ldots , x_M \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} $ satisfying $$\sum_{j=1}^M x_j = 1?$$ Clearly $\tau \leq 4$ and for $M = 2$, we have that $\tau = \log_2 6$.

Comment: If the question is ""what is the smallest $\tau$ such that for all $M$...", then, obviously, $3$. If it is "For a fixed $M$, find the smallest tau...", then it is, most likely, intractable beyond a few small values.

Comment: That's my guess too. I would also be happy with a bound of the form $\tau \leq 3 - c/ \log M$ for some $c > 0$.

Comment: OK, now it is something to think of :-)

Comment: Actually I think I have that bound by now (I'll need some paper to check the pesky details). If correct, I'll post the argument later in the evening :-)

Comment: @fedja Cool! I am certainly interested in making $c$ as large as possible. I believe one cannot take $c$ bigger than $\log (3/2)$.

Comment: OK, done by now, take a look. BTW, what is this good for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed the gap. Now the argument should be complete. Feel free to ask questions if something is unclear.

The problem is equivalent to showing that the $L^4$ norm of a trigonometric polynomial $P(z)=\sum_{k=1}^My_kz^k$ on the unit circle $\mathbb T$ with the Haar measure $\mu$ can be bounded (with constant $1$) by the $\ell^{p}$ norm of its coefficient sequence with $p=\frac43+\frac c{\log M}$ ($y_k^p=x_k$). We assume that the latter norm is $1$. Note that it implies that the $\ell^{4/3}$-norm of the coefficient sequence is then at most $a(c)$ where $a(c)\to 1$ as $c\to 0+$.

*Case 1:* There exists a coefficient close to $1$. Assume that it is $y_j=1-\varepsilon$. Then
$$
\int|P|^4\,d\mu=\int |Pz^{-j}|^4\,d\mu=\int [(1-\varepsilon)+Q]^2[(1-\varepsilon)+\bar Q]^2\,d\mu
$$
where $Q$ is a mean $0$ trigonometric polynomial with the $\ell^p$ norm of its coefficient sequence at most $[1-(1-\varepsilon)^p]^{1/p}\le 2\varepsilon^{1/p}$, so the $\ell^{4/3}$, $\ell^{3/2}$, and $\ell^2$ norms of the coefficient sequence of $Q$ are bounded by $3\varepsilon^{1/p}$, say, provided that $c>0$ is small enough. Opening the parentheses, integrating, and using Hausdorff-Young, we conclude that our integral is bounded by 
$$
(1-\varepsilon)^4+C[\varepsilon^{2/p}+\varepsilon^{3/p}+\varepsilon^{4/p}]
$$
with some absolute $C>0$.
Since all powers in brackets are strictly bigger than $1$, we stay below $1$ as long as $0\le\varepsilon\le\varepsilon_0$ for some $\varepsilon_0>0$.

*Case 2:* The coefficients are separated from $1$ by some $\varepsilon_0>0$. We shall show that in this case the sum on the left with $\tau=3$ (in the original notation) is bounded by $\gamma=\gamma(\varepsilon_0)<1$. Since it has about $M^3$ terms, the desired improvement will follow immediately just by the Holder inequality.

Note first of all that $(DCBA)^{1/4}\le \frac 14(D+C+B+A)$ and that if the ratio $B/A$, say, is outside the interval $I=[1-\varepsilon_1,1+\varepsilon_1]$ with some $\varepsilon_1>0$, then we can introduce a factor $\Gamma=\Gamma(\varepsilon_1)<1$ on the right hand side.

Now we can write 
$$
(x_ax_bx_cx_d)^{3/4}\le\frac 14[x_ax_bx_c+x_ax_bx_d+x_ax_cx_d+x_bx_cx_d]
$$
Moreover, if $x_a/x_b\notin I$, we can introduce the factor $\Gamma$ on the right hand side.

Now suppose that for all $a$, we have $\sum_{b:x_a/x_b\notin I}x_b>\delta>0$. Then we get an immediate improvement 
$$
\sum_{a,b:x_a/x_b\in I}x_ax_b+\Gamma\sum_{a,b:x_a/x_b\notin I}x_ax_b\le 1-(1-\Gamma)\delta\,.
$$
Otherwise the main part of $x_k$ (in terms of the sum) lies in a short (on the logarithmic scale) interval, which means that, provided $\delta>0$ is small enough, we should get the sum close to $1$  from that part alone if our claim does not hold. This part cannot be a singleton (otherwise we are in Case 1) Thus, it remains to show that for any finite set $A$ of integers with $|A|\ge 2$, we have
$$
\int|R|^4\,d\mu\le \gamma_2|A|^3
$$
with some absolute $\gamma_2<1$ where $R(z)=\sum_{a\in A}z^a$

This last part is easier to do combinatorially. Let $N=|A|\ge 2$. For every $k\in\mathbb Z$ define $D_k=\#\{a\in A:a+k\in A\}$. Then the LHS is just $\sum_k D_k^2$. Notice that $\sum_k D_k=N^2$ and $D_k\le N$. Thus, the only way not to have a constant improvement over the trivial $N^3$ bound is to have at least $0.9N$ integers $k$ for which $D_k>0.9N$. Let $B$ be the set of such $k$. Then $|B|\ge 0.9N$. However if $k,\ell\in B$, then
$$
D_{k-\ell}\ge \#\{a\in A:a+k\in A, a+\ell\in A\}\ge 0.8N 
$$
Thus $B-B\subset C$ where $C=\{k:D_k\ge 0.8N\}$. However, by the identity $\sum_k D_k=N^2$, we get $|C|\le 1.25N<1.8N-1\le 2|B|-1$, which is impossible
(this is a trivial sumset theorem: if $B=\{b_1<b_2<\dots<b_L\}$, then
$B-B\supset\{b_1-b_L<b_1-b_{L-1}<b_2-b_{L-1}<\dots<b_L-b_1\}$).

Comment: Thanks for your response! It seems that your argument works, but I am still trying to convince myself that all the cases you handled are really all of the possible cases. This is a generalization of a problem solved in a paper of Kane and Tao ($M = 2$). There is another application, but somehow it does not fit in the margins..I'd be happy to discuss this more via email if you're interested!

Comment: Alright I'm pretty much convinced, very nice! One can take $\gamma_2 = 3/4$, with equality iff $|A| = 2$ (using the energy version of the trivial sumset theorem).

Comment: The type of bound George wants would also follow if, on the physical side, we could improve Young's inequality by a multiplicative constant < 1. This is done by Charalambides and Christ https://arxiv.org/1112.3716, for functions that are far from functions supported at a point. They seem to use some similar ingredients to Fedja's argument (e.g. Cauchy-Davenport).